# Не срабатывает хендлер aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, state, setstate

Прочитал документацию aiogram по состояниям, сделал структуру базовую, но почему-то не работает 2 хендлер. В состояниях еще не сильно разбираюсь)
Вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT, state='*')
async def text_handler(message: types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.text == labels.USER_MENU_BTN_1:
        await state.update_data(user_id=message.from_user.id)
        await message.reply(labels.CATEGORY_CHOOSE_MSG, reply=False, reply_markup=keyboards.question_category_list())
        await Form.category.set()
    elif message.text == labels.BACK_BTN:
        await message.reply(labels.BACK_MSG, reply=False, reply_markup=keyboards.user_menu())
        await state.reset_state()
        await state.reset_data()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT, state=Form.category)
async def category_set(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == labels.CATEGORY_BTN_1:
        await message.reply(labels.CATEGORY_CHOSEN_MSG.format(category=message.text), reply=False,
                            reply_markup=keyboards.back_keyboard())
    elif message.text == labels.CATEGORY_BTN_2:
        await message.reply(labels.CATEGORY_CHOSEN_MSG.format(category=message.text), reply=False,
                            reply_markup=keyboards.back_keyboard())
    elif message.text == labels.CATEGORY_BTN_3:
        await message.reply(labels.CATEGORY_CHOSEN_MSG.format(category=message.text), reply=False,
                            reply_markup=keyboards.back_keyboard())
    await state.update_data(category=message.text)
    await message.reply(labels.QUESTION_TEXT_MSG, reply=False, reply_markup=keyboards.back_keyboard())
    await Form.next()
```

Код файла states, который импортируется так from states import Form:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup


class Form(StatesGroup):
    user_id = State()
    category = State()
    text = State()
```

Если еще что-то нужно добавлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Штош. Фикситься это в пару кликов. Берешь нижний хендлер, вырезаешь его и вставляешь над хендлером который сейчас выше.

Не срабатывает он по довольно просто причине: хендлеры проверяются по порядку сверху внизу. То есть если где-то условие подходит, то следующие хендлеры игнорируются.

В твоём случае `@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT, state='*')`
срабатывает на все что является текстом и с любым стейтом (то есть хоть None, хоть какой-то определенный стейт) потому второй и не срабатывает.

Comment: Спасибо большое!